# Is there a keyboard shortcuts for switching tabs at Safari?

Tags: safari

At Photoshop, you can use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> to switch tabs, is there a keyboard shortcuts for switching tabs at Safari?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select previous tab: ⌃⇧⇥ (control-shift-tab), ⇧⌘← (shift-command-left), or ⇧⌘[ (shift-command-[)
Select next tab: ⌃⇥ (control-tab), ⇧⌘→ (shift-command-right), or ⇧⌘] (shift-command-])

You can customize the shortcuts from System Preferences:

[image]

Comment: A perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

These shortcuts are found in the Window menu.

[image: 123]

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Oh boy...I just asked a stupid question. Thanks for the help!